# Listbox doesn't show new row after updating the datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

First and foremost I am in C# and using Visual Studio 2010 and still a student in this.

I have a listbox that displays the name of the Administrators in my Database.
When I add another Admin to the Database, the update is done in the Database but the name is not added to the listbox.

I've tried reading lots of posts on this issue but none of the answers works for me. Thank you in advance for your help.
So here is the faulty portion of my code :

```
class adminDAO
    {
        public static Administration admin;
        private static Connexion connect;
        private static OleDbDataReader reader;
        private static OleDbCommandBuilder cmdBuilder;
        private static OleDbDataAdapter da_Admin;
        private static DataSet ds_Admin;
        private static DataTable tableAdmin = new DataTable("Administrateurs");

        private static int nbLignes = 0;

        public static void getListAdmin()
        {
            string req = "SELECT * FROM Administrateurs";
            da_Admin = new OleDbDataAdapter(req, connect.dbconnect);
            ds_Admin = new DataSet();
            da_Admin.Fill(ds_Admin, "Administrateurs");
            tableAdmin = new DataTable("Administrateurs");

            da_Admin.Fill(tableAdmin);

            admin.bS_Admin.DataSource = tableAdmin;
            admin.lb_admin.DataSource = admin.bS_Admin;
            admin.lb_admin.DataBindings.Add("Text", admin.bS_Admin, "nomAdmin");

            nbLignes = ds_Admin.Tables["Administrateurs"].Rows.Count;
        }

        public static void setAdmin(string nomAdmin, string username, string password)
        {
            connect = Connexion.getConnexion();

            try
            {
                nbLignes = nbLignes + 1;
                cmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da_Admin);

                string req = "INSERT INTO Administrateurs VALUES(@noAdmin, @nomAdmin, @username, @password)";
                OleDbCommand insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(req, connect.dbconnect);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@noAdmin", nbLignes);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomAdmin", nomAdmin);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                da_Admin.Update(tableAdmin);

            }
            catch(OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erreur de mise à jour : " + ex.Message);
            }
            connect.exitConnexion();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try after removing the instantiation of static datatable object inside getListAdmin()

i.e remove `tableAdmin = new DataTable("Administrateurs");` inside getListAdmin() method

Comment: I tried but the listbox still doesn't update after removing the instantiation in getListAdmin().

Comment: Only your data layer code is shared here. It is difficult to understand how your UI work.Please ensure that you again call getListAdmin() from UI after saving the new records to database. for e.g if you are saving the records in a button click the code would be - `public void button_click(object sender, eventargs e){adminDAO.SetAdmin();adminDAO.getListAdmin()}`

Comment: didn't change the result but I have finally managed to get the ListBox to update by clearing the table then filling it again. Thanks for the help.